# Img srcset: How to use specific sizes?

Tags: html, image, size, srcset

I have an image that I want to swap out at specific twitter bootstrap breakpoints. These are 768, 992 & 1200px.

I have a different size img for each of these breakpoints. 720px for min 768px wide, 616px for min 992px wide & 750px for min 1200px wide.

I have followed the img srcset docs but I cannot get the right one to load for 992px wide. See my code below:

```
 <img data-no-retina class="img-responsive" 

 src="/img/100vw.jpg" 

sizes="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) 720px,
(min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) 616px, 
(min-width: 1200px) 750px, 100vw" 

 srcset="/img/720px.jpg 720w, 
 /img/616px.jpg 616w, 
 /img/750px.jpg, 750w" 

 alt="Some description">
```

Comment: Actually this works fine, it does not work as expected in Chrome Dev Tools Responsive mode. There may be a bug there.

Comment: In Chrome Dev tool, it also considers into account the pixel density.